# How to convert Hex to Dec and vice-versa in c#

Tags: c#

I have a Hex values as below , And i wan't to convert this hex to decimal value with Signed Value.

i use System.Convert.ToUInt32() method to convert the hex string value to decimal string Value.

C# Code:

```
        String hs = "FFFFFFDF";    //Hex value which i got 
        uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
        string character = decval.ToString();
```

when i try to convert this i got unsigned Decimal value.so give some tips to make my code print the proper decimal value with signed value.

Comment: Did you try `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `ToUInt32()`?

Comment: Thanks René Vogt ,it's worked for me i got perfect answer this time i.e -33